# How to do lemmatization in R using Wordnet?

Tags: r, wordnet, lemmatization

I want to lemmatize the corpus using Wordnet's getLemma function in R. But I am not pretty sure how to use it.

Here is the documentation given for lemmatization using wordnet package in R..

```
filter <- getTermFilter("StartsWithFilter", "car", TRUE)
terms <- getIndexTerms("NOUN", 5, filter)
sapply(terms, getLemma)
```

my question is I have a document containing 5000 words and in this case I want to convert each of the word into its base/root word.     Ex: fever --> fever  ;  feverish --> fever

I want to lemmatize all the words in the corpus and would not restrict it to words StartingWith...,  I also dont understand the significance of the number 5 in `terms <- getIndexTerms("NOUN", 5, filter)`

It would be great if somebody can solve this for me.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you want to get answers, you should provide a reproducible example, and describe what you already tried to do...

Comment: filter <- getTermFilter("StartsWithFilter", "car", TRUE)                  terms <- getIndexTerms("NOUN", 5, filter)                               sapply(terms, getLemma)                                                              I want to lemmatize all the words in the corpus and would not restrict it to words StartingWith..., I also dont understand the significance of the number 5 in "terms <- getIndexTerms("NOUN", 5, filter)"

Answer (score 0):

The 5 refers to maxLimit which is the maximum number of results you want...
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wordnet/wordnet.pdf  <--this has all you need to solve your problem